# Showing that $\frac{1-|z|^2}{|\xi-z|^2}$ is harmonic if $\xi$ fixed

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\xi\in \partial K(0,1)$. Define $u_\xi$ by
$$u_\xi(z)=\frac{1-|z|^2}{|\xi-z|^2}.$$
How do you show that $u_\xi$ is harmonic on $K(0,1)$? Using the Laplaceoperator seems tricky here, as I can't find the imaginary part. Thus, I thought about finding a holomorphic function $f$ such that $\Re f=u_\xi$. After having rewritten $u_\xi$, I got stuck:
$$\frac{1-|z|^2}{|\xi-z|^2}=\frac{1}{\xi-z}\overline{\left ( \frac{1}{\xi-z} \right )}-\frac{z}{\xi-z}\overline{\left ( \frac{z}{\xi-z} \right )}.$$

Comment: Something something Poisson kernel....

Comment: Isn't $0$ the imaginary part? Both $1-|z|^2$ and $|\xi-z|^2$ are real.

Comment: @ajotatxe $u_\xi$ is the real part. I meant to find a holomorphic $f$ satisfying $\Re f = u_\xi$. I have edited the post.

Comment: Similar question: [Proving a function is harmonic without calculating partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441496/proving-a-function-is-harmonic-without-calculating-partial-derivatives).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
u_\xi(z)
&=
\frac{1-|z|^2}{|\xi-z|^2} \\
&=
\frac{\xi\bar{\xi}-\xi\bar{z} +\xi\bar{z}-|z|^2}{(\xi-z)(\bar{\xi}-\bar{z})} \\
&=
\frac{\xi\bar{\xi}-\xi\bar{z}}{(\xi-z)(\bar{\xi}-\bar{z})}+\frac{\xi\bar{z}-z\bar{z}}{(\xi-z)(\bar{\xi}-\bar{z})} \\
&=
\frac{\xi}{\xi-z}+\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{\xi}-\bar{z}} \\
&=
h+\bar{g}
\end{align}
where $h$ and $g$ are analytic.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the real part of $\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}?$

Comment: How about $$\frac{1+z}{1-z}={\color{red}{\frac{(1-\Re z)^2-(\Im z)^2}{|1+z|^2}}}+i\frac{2(1-\Re z)(\Im z)}{|1+z|^2},$$ so the imaginary part must be the first term on the right side of the equality sign (red color).